# How can one read files from an SD card in Android 7.0?

Tags: java, android

For a previous telephone (Android 4.0) I wrote an app which uses data files which I copy to the SD card from a PC, using a USB cable. The app uses Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() to retrieve the files, as advised by many sites.

On a telephone with Android 7.0, this app no longer works.  Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() returns "storage/emulated/0/" which maps to *internal* storage. I tried getExternalStoragePublicDirectory, but this references the same location.

So I tried a hard-coded "/sdcard". This also does not reference the SD card. On writing a test file to that location from an app, I found the file using the File Commander app in internal storage, but the file could not be found either in internal storage or on the SD card using Windows Explorer on the PC, so it is not clear to me where it really is. In my web searching I have seen references to /sdcard0 and /sdcard1 but testing these revealed that neither exists on my telephone.

My main question is therefore: how do I get hold of the root directory of the SD card in Android 7.0 and later versions, given that getExternalStorageDirectory() does not provide this?

And a subsidiary question: what is the point of a getExternalStorageDirectory() function which does not get the external storage directory?

Comment: what getExternalStorageState returns?

Comment: `what is the point of a getExternalStorageDirectory() function which does not get the external storage directory?` Well it does as the inbuild storage is called that way. You are more looking for removable storage.

Answer (score 1):

You could look at the second item returned by `getExternalFilesDirs()` to find your app specific directory on the SD card.

But if you want to update your app to modern standards then have a look at `Storage Access Framework` using `Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` and or `StorageVolumes`.

Comment: That is a small step forward - thanks. The second item returned by getExternalFilesDirs() is indeed a directory on the SD card. But it's an empty subdirectory five levels down under Android/Data. I suppose I could GetAbsolutePath() and trim levels off until I get back to the root of the SD card, but that seems like a horrible hack. Is there really not a more elegant method, short of substantially rewriting the app?

Comment: `That is a small step forward ` ?? I disagree! That is THE step for you. And no that is not a horrible hack. That is a good method.Every body does. But you then can only read. In the original directory you can read/write.

Comment: `Is there really not a more elegant method` Storage Access Framework.

Comment: `But it's an empty subdirectory` Of course. Then what would you expect? But someone created that directory... Starting with the Android directory...  isn't it a mistery?